# How to run a task after compileDebugSources with Build Variants and Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

For building an Android library I copy some source code from other Java modules to the source folders of my Android library.

After compiling those source code files I want to delete those copied source code files.

The Android library I build with two flavors: `FlavorA` and `FlavorB`

I mangaged this using `build.gralde` based on Groovy:

```
afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.doFirst {
        copySourceCodeFromOtherModules()
    }

    compileFlavorADebugSources.doLast {
        cleanSrcCode()
    }
    compileFlavorBDebugSources.doLast {
        cleanSrcCode()
    }
}
```

Now I switched my whole project to `build.gralde.kts` based on Kotlin DSL.

I tried

```
tasks.named("preBuild") {
    doFirst {
        copySourceCodeFromOtherModules()
    }
}

tasks.named("compileFlavorADebugSources") {
    doLast {
        cleanSrcCode()
    }
}

tasks.named("compileFlavorBDebugSources") {
    doLast {
        cleanSrcCode()
    }
}
```

The function `copySourceCodeFromOtherModules()` is called as desired. But for `tasks.named("compileFlavorADebugSources")` I get an build error: `Task with name 'compileFlavorADebugSources' not found in project ':myAndroidLib'.`

How can I extend the "compile"-tasks with Kotlin DSL.

PS: I googled a lot :-(